# How do I use a relative path to access a png file

Tags: python, image, tkinter, path

So I am running this code:

```
from tkinter import *

# Variables
HomeGUI = Tk()
CamBut = Button(HomeGUI)
CamLogo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\adity\PycharmProjects\Front End for MediScan\CamLogo.PNG")


# Function opens GUI for home screen
def runhome():
    # Setting global variables
    global CamBut
    global HomeGUI

    CamBut.config(image=CamLogo)
    CamBut.pack()
    HomeGUI.mainloop()


runhome()
```

And I want to be able to access CamLogo.PNG using a relative path, as the direct path will not work on another device, how could I do this? CamLogo.png is in the same folder as the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If its in the same folder then you'd simply do:

```py
CamLogo = PhotoImage(file="CamLogo.PNG")
```

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. This will open a file in the current working directory which might not be the same folder as the script.

Comment: See OP's last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If the PNG is in the same directory as the Python script then you could just refer to it by its basename.

However, what happens when someone modifies your code and adds os.chdir('some other directory')? Then that strategy won't work.

This would be safer:

```
import os

myPNG = 'CamLogo.PNG'

pathToPNG = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), myPNG)
```

Then you can use pathToPNG without worrying about any possible changes of directory elsewhere in your code.

Of course, pathToPNG will be absolute but it's a more robust approach

Comment: _"If the PNG is in the same directory as the Python script then you could just refer to it by its basename."_ - this is only true if the current working directory is the same as the location of the script.